# @RequestParam and @PathVariable on the same variable in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, request-mapping

In my Spring boot microservice I need to have dedicated endpoint that maps next urls

- `/delivery-options/myLabel`
- `/delivery-options?label=myLabel`

For handling both I try to use both `@RequestParam` and `@PathVariable` for my controller's method parameter but it does not work for both situations

```
@RequestMapping({"/delivery-options", "/delivery-options/{label}"})
public ResponseEntity<?> getDeliveryOptions(@RequestParam(value = "label", required = false) @PathVariable(value = "label", required = false) String label ) {

}
```

Is it possible to map both to one variable?

Comment: map these values to 2 different variables then assign these values to another variable.

Comment: I thought about it, it's interesting if it's possible to use more advanced way to do it.

Comment: Use @MatrixVariable

Answer (score 1):

I believe we can only do this by assigning to two different variables and making both required to false.

I know this is not the solution you are looking for and also i believe the other way is declaring two different methods and mapping each request to one of them, even though that not makes the duplicate code because you are handling request and mapping to service layer based on input

```
@RequestMapping(value= {"/hello/{hi}","/hellodiff"}, method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void hello(@PathVariable(value="hi", required=false) String hi, 
@RequestParam(value="key", required=false) String key) {
    System.out.println("Output: "+ hi +" "+ key);

}
```

Output:

```
localhost:8080/hello/hey
Output: hey null

localhost:8080/hellodiff?key="cool"
Output: null "cool"
```